# Update user contact email addresses using Microsoft Graph

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to update the phone numbers and email addresses to update an contact's email addresses and phone numbers, using the microsoft.graph module in powerShell.

Authentication is done via an app registration with the needed permissions.

Data to input is extracted from AAD and stored in the variable $AadUser

Trying to update the email address to username@domain.com I get the following:

```
Update-MgUserContact -ContactId $CurrentContact.Id -UserId $ContactManagementMailboxId -EmailAddresses @{$AadUser.Mail = $AadUser.DisplayName}
Update-MgUserContact : The annotation 'domain.com' was targeting the instance annotation 'username'. Only the 'odata.type' annotation is allowed to target an instance annotation.
At line:1 char:1
+ Update-MgUserContact -ContactId $CurrentContact.Id -UserId $ContactMa ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: ({ UserId = 424c...GraphContact1 }:<>f__AnonymousType38`3) [Update-MgUserContact_UpdateExpanded1], RestException`1
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RequestBodyRead,Microsoft.Graph.PowerShell.Cmdlets.UpdateMgUserContact_UpdateExpanded1
```

I am sure something is wrong with the hash table used to pass the email address, but I can't see what...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> @{$AadUser.Mail = $AadUser.DisplayName}

Doesn't look correct it should be an object array where the object has two property name and address eg

```
Update-MgUserContact -ContactId $contact.Id -EmailAddresses @{name="Sue";address="sue@dom.com"}
```

in your example something like

```
-EmailAddresses @{name=$AadUser.DisplayName;address=$AadUser.Mail}
```

should work